# literal controls height and width?

Tags: asp.net

in my application i am using literal controls in data list , now i want to apply height and width for the literal controls is it possible for applying height and width to literal controls. thank  you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do one thing use literal control in the div control. and assign height and width to div control because literal control is render on page as static text.

For example

```
<div style="height:10px;width10px;">
     <asp:Literal ID="Literal3" runat="Server" Text="Just a text inside Literal  
              Control"></asp:Literal> 
<div>
```

Comment: ya mr. pranay_stacker i try this one but it is not working. actually i am binding video embeded code to the literal control in a datalist the videos are overlap.

Comment: i got the solution i change width and height of the embeded now it is working

Answer (score 0):

Place the Literal in a container say div, span etc and apply the width to the container. Use `style="word-wrap:break-word"`  along with width to make the content fit within the container.

Answer (score 0):

add style below for iframe tags then you'll have it done

```
<style>
    iframe{
        width: 100%;
    }
</style>
```